# How do I check if 2 variables have something in them and the other doesn't?

Tags: javascript

I would like output the values of `var1`, `var2` and `var3` and my code to check if 1 variable exists or not is this:

```
if (var1){
 return value = "some value -";  
} else
 return '';  
}
```

but what if there are 1 or more variable that needs checking like `var1` exists and `var2` doesnt etc.,

```
if (var1 && !var2 && var3){
 //do something
}else if (var1 && !var2 && !var3){    
 //do something
}else
 return '';
```

What am I doing wrong? Basically what I want is to just append a dash on a string so that I can get the output of `some value - some value` and not get `some value -` if a variable is empty.

Comment: please show all relevant code. and input value that is not working. We have no idea what these variables are

Comment: @sky Sounds like a case of "[combinatorial explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion)" -- it's easier and more maintainable to check each variable separately like they're doing in the answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the values in an array and use `.join`.

```
var values = [];
if (value1) {
    values.push(value1);
}
if (value2) {
    values.push(value2);
}
if (value3) {
    values.push(value3);
}
return values.join(" - ");
```

This easily extends to an arbitrary number of variables. Although perhaps they should just be in an array to begin with, rather than separate variables. You can use `values.filter()` to filter out the empty values before joining.

Answer (score 1):

```
var var1;
var var2 = "1";
var var3 = "11";
var start = false;
var text = "";

if (var1) {
    text += var1;
    start = true;
}
if (var2) {
    if (start)
        text += " - ";
    text += var2;
    start = true;
}
if (var3) {
    if (start)
        text += " - ";
    text += var3;
}

console.log(text);
```

Comment: `document.write` -- really?